# GKTurnBasedMatch recognizing the playergroup

Tags: request, game-center, multiplayer, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I' m working on a gamekit turnbased match. It's a wordgame in different languages.

The player has the option to set the language for every game he wants to play.
I would like to use the GKMatchRequest's playergroup property to differentiate between the languages.

But after the GKMatchRequest has been sent and I receive a GKTurnBasedMatch object, how can I tell which playergroup (language) belongs to that match ?
As far as I know, the GKTurnBasedMatch object doesn't have the playergroup property nor can I match a GKTurnBasedMatch object with a GKMatchRequest, there's no identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't a `playerGroup` property in a `GKTurnBasedMatch` object, I recommend storing the playerGroup of the match in the `matchData` property.

Answer (score 0):

The GKTurnBasedMatch you receive is of the playerGroup you requested.
If you set your playerGroup to 1, the GKTurnBasedMatch you get back will only pair up when someone else requests a match with a playerGroup of 1.

From the documentation: "If your application sets the playerGroup property, only players whose requests share the same playerGroup value are automatched by Game Center"